# PHP - Remove quotes in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a MySQL query from within a function being called by a search form, giving in 2 values, $Search & $dropdown.

To prevent MySQL injection I am trying to bind the values as below:

```
$database->query('SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE :dropdown like :Search');
$database->bind(dropdown, $dropdown);
$database->bind(Search,$Search);
$getServers = $database->fetchall();
```

In the MariaDB logs I found the query was executed as below:

```
SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE 'rackid' like '5';
```

The problem is that the column name:('rackid'), is executed with quotes which  give 0 output, if I manually execute the same code without the quotes as below I get the desired ouput.

```
SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE rackid like '5';
```

Is there a way to prevent the code from adding the single quotes to the variables in the mysql statement?

Comment: (Oh bother, didn't notice that duplicate was for Oracle. The answer is the same for MySQL though)

Comment: Have you thought about using prepared statements with [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) ?

Comment: The statement I am using is a modified version of the PDO.

After Quentin pointed out the other answer, it brought me in the right direction and after some research I found out that table and column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. 

So as a workaround I made a switch statement for every column name.